# Is there a way to be able to flip an FlxCamera to the x axis?

Tags: camera, haxe, haxeflixel

`setScale()` doesn't work either.
I was going to flip the camera for when something interesting happens, but I don't how how.

Answer (score 0):

You could flip the camera (and apply other interesting effects) with shaders!

`FlxCamera` has a function called `setFilters()` that allows you to add a list of bitmap filters to an active camera.

Here's a simple filter I wrote that flips all textures horizontally:

```
import openfl.filters.ShaderFilter;

var filters:Array<BitmapFilter> = [];

// Add a filter that flips everything horizontally
var filter = new ShaderFilter(new FlipXAxis());
filters.push(filter);

// Apply filters to camera
FlxG.camera.setFilters(filters);
```

And in a separate class called `FlipXAxis`:

```
import flixel.system.FlxAssets.FlxShader;

class FlipXAxis extends FlxShader
{
    @:glFragmentSource('
        #pragma header

        void main()
        {
                vec2 uv = vec2(1.0 - openfl_TextureCoordv.x, openfl_TextureCoordv.y);
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(bitmap, uv);
        }')
    public function new()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```